# Can't access value of named array keys in PHP/Twig

Tags: php, twig

I have a PHP array like this:

index.php:

```
$state = [
  'isLoggedIn' => false,
  'isB2BCustomer' => false
];

print($twig->render('index.html', ['state' => $state]));
```

index.html:

```
{% for key, stateItem in state %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ key }}: {{ stateItem }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This gives me the following output:

```
|---------------------|
| State               |
|---------------------|
| isLoggedIn:         |
|---------------------|
| isB2BCustomer:      |
|---------------------|
```

I'm expecting:

```
|---------------------|
| State               |
|---------------------|
| isLoggedIn: 0       |
|---------------------|
| isB2BCustomer: 0    |
|---------------------|
```

It shows the keys correctly, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the value.

Comment: Why would you expect `0` for `false`??? https://3v4l.org/DlR10 You'll either need to store `0` or display an actual `0` when the value is `false`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Twig/PHP outputs booleans as integers right? I'm just doing this as a test to access the values, so I put them in a table to see them. And I expect the `false` values to be output as `0`. Any idea about how to access the values?

Comment: I don't know twig but PHP doesn't output `false`, maybe `{% if stateItem %}1{% else %}0{% endif%}` or somesuch.

Comment: @AbraCadaver You're right, booleans simply aren't displayed at all like you said. I remember boolean values were automatically type casted to integers (either 0 or 1), but I remember wrong I think. Thanks this solved it.

Comment: _"A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string values."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{% for key, stateItem in state %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ key }}: {{ stateItem ? '1' : '0' }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Found here:
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#other-operators